# Time limit exceeded in a number of steps game

Tags: c, time, limit

I'm trying to solve the following interviewbit question:

Given a target A on an infinite number line, i.e. -infinity to +infinity.

You are currently at position 0 and you need to reach the target by moving according to the below rule:

In ith move you can take i steps forward or backward.
Find the minimum number of moves required to reach the target.

Input Format
First and only argument is an integer A.

Output Format
Return an integer denoting the minimum moves to reach target.

My code:

```
int solve(int A) {
    int B=0;
    int i =1;
    int count =0;
    
    if(A<0){
        A = A*(-1);
    }

    while(A!=B)
    {
        if(A>(B+i)){
            count++;
            B=B+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if(A<(B+i)){
            count++;
            B=B-i;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

It always give time limit exceeded error. I'm trying to understand how to avoid that, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Driver, I think you only attempt going backward when you are already beyond the target. I would expect that it is often necessary to go backward a step while not yet over target. Let me know if I misread your code or if you doubt my feeling.

Comment: `solve(1)` doesn't terminate in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: It's a style note, but the `+=`, `-=`, *=`, etc. operators might be useful here.

Comment: `i++` and `count++` are the some in either branch so can be moved out.  Other than initialized differently they move in lock step so you only need one of them.

Comment: What are the intermediate values your program calculates for a target of 35? Please output them and report them here. I think that example will show you how your program misses the optimal solution (9 steps) and how it will predictably never find any. If I am right it means that you do not only have a time limit exceeded problem, your program fails already logically. By the way, please have a look at   https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If you show the intermediate values I think you will spot the algorithm which will get you a correct result AND in much better time than simulation/brute forcing, with just one loop. I.e. good chances of getting it logically right and within time limit. If not I will be happy to hint you. This would be according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions good luck. If that is not enough, the next step of optimisation, to a fully constructive approach, is via https://oeis.org (as in many TLE cases....).

Comment: `if(A<0){
        A = A*(-1);
    }` ===> Use `abs()` from `math.h`.

Comment: Or... tertiary `A = A <= 0 ? A : -A;`.  Not sure it's the right thing to do anyways.

Comment: `if(A>(B+i)){
            count++;
            B=B+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if(A<(B+i)){
            count++;
            B=B-i;
            i++;` ===> ```A > (B + i) ? B += i : B -= i;   count++; i++;```

Comment: @Haris I get the impression that you are trying to offer a code-only solution as answer. Please use an answer to do so. But also please confirm that you are aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions If on the other hand your code proposals do not actually solve OPs problem then you might consider to ... not?

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh, I'm actually not providing a code-only solution (I haven't read the question description) . I only thought the tertiary operator would be more readable to the OP. :)

Comment: @driver You do not need `i` at all. Simply do `B--` and `B++`.

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I did not miss it.  The question is internally inconsistent: "A on an infinite number line," and "integer A".  Op says this is an "interviewbit question" (i.e. interview prep) but you link to a discussion on homework?  I stand by my opinion that it's dumb (senseless) using puzzle questions in an interview context as that is nothing like the job you are likely to perform.  Unlike, say, debugging.   I didn't know of oeis.org; what a cool resource.

Comment: @Yunnosch In math context, no, but this is SO so op is mapping "integer" to "int" which makes sense and those things are different (you can't express INT_MAX + 1, or infinite).

Comment: Let me put it differently. The target A is given, as an "integer" (which I read the math way) and probably somewhere else is defined, or a reasonable guess, that it can be stored in an `int` or `long int`. I am with you in that. The point is that A is a given value, not infinity. And you yourself assumed that it can be stored in beginner level way, i.e. not big int trickery. With that I find your (by now deleted) comment problematic, that with infinite A the time is infinite (or similar, I can't confirm anymore). @AllanWind

Comment: @AllanWind Now the problem that OP faces is not related to inifinity, it is not related to TLE, it is in fact caused by logic failure of the program - independent of duration. Infinity only comes into the problem because OPs attempt would take infinite time, or more precisely, never end - even for very small values of correct solutions like 9 for steps for 35. I am trying to guide them to that insight. I offer to help them further to get a logically correct solution with decent time (by searching in O(n)) and even further to a formula based calculation with no loop.

Comment: If you get a question about a problem like this in an interview, then they're just trying to trip you up. Either you've encountered this specific problem before and know there's a simpl-ish answer, or you haven't and can't reasonably be expected to come up with one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being asked to find the smallest n such that ±1±2±3±...±n = A.

Let T(N) = 1+2+...+N.

Assume A is positive (otherwise negate it). Let N be the smallest integer such that T(N) = 1+2+...+N >= A.

- If T(N) = A, then the solution is N.
- If T(N) - A is even, then the solution is still N (change the sign of (T(N)-A)/2 in 1+2+...+N).
- If T(N) - A is odd and N is even, then the solution is N+1 (change the sign of (T(N)+N+1-A)/2 in 1+2+...+N+(N+1)).
- If T(N) - A is odd and N is odd, then the solution is N+2 (change the sign of (T(N)+1-A)/2 in 1+2+...+N-(N+1)+(N+2)).

It's easy to see that these solutions are optimal: the solution in each case is the smallest n such that T(n)>=A and T(n)-A is even (T(n)-A is odd is impossible, because ±1±2±3±...±n - A is odd (and hence not 0) when T(n)-A is odd).

You can find the smallest N with T(N) >= A by solving a quadratic equation (since T(N)=N(N+1)/2).

An example for each case:

- A=10. T(4)=10, T(4)=A so the the answer is 4: 1+2+3+4=10.
- A=11. T(5)=15. T(5)-11=4 is even, so the answer is 5: 1-2+3+4+5=11.
- A=9. T(4)=10. T(4)-9=1 is odd, but N is even, so the answer is 5: 1+2-3+4+5=9.
- A=12. T(5)=15. T(5)-12=3 is odd, and N is odd, so the answer is 7: 1-2+3+4+5-6+7=12.

A solution will look something like this (untested):

```
A = abs(A);
int N = ceil((sqrt(8*A + 1) - 1) / 2);
if ((N*(N+1)/2 - A) % 2) ++N;
if ((N*(N+1)/2 - A) % 2) ++N;
printf("%d\n", N);
```

Or you can write a simpler version that runs in sqrt(A) time:

```
int N=1;
while (N*(N+1)/2 < abs(A) || (N*(N+1)/2 - abs(A)) % 2) N++;
printf("%d\n", N);
```

Comment: Cool.  In the untested solution the double `if` line doesn't look right.   Where does the sqrt come from?  I am guessing it's the solution to quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

When the next move would, in the positive direction, make `B` equal to `A`, neither `A>(B+i)` nor `A<(B+i)` is true, because `A == B+i` is true. In that case, your program does nothing in the loop. `B` is not changed. So the loop with `A!=B` continues. It does nothing again and again, without stopping. Then your program exceeds the time limit and is terminated.

In the case where `A == B+i`, you want to move in the positive direction. So the test `A>(B+i)` should be `A >= B+i`. Then the test in `else if(A<(B+i))` is redundant; it should just be `else`.

That will give you an algorithm that terminates if it finds a sequence of steps that gets to the target. You should prove that it always finds a sequence and that it finds the minimum sequence. (Hint: It is not, so you need to find a new algorithm. For example, consider A = 4. Your algorithm uses +1 +2 −3 +4, which is four moves. However, four steps can be accomplished with -1 +2 +3, which is three moves.)

There is a way to find the minimum number of steps directly, using algebra and a fixed amount of calculation, without using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm doesn't work (terminate) for even simple input.  For instance `solve(1)` results in an infinite loop as neither of the two `if` conditions apply.

Even if that technical issue is fixed, it would not work, for example `solve(2)` would evaluate the positions 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, ... which is 4+ moves. The counter example is where we simply alternative between adding and subtract and positions being are now 0, 1, -1, 2 which is 3 moves.

There may be a clever algorithm, not knowing it, I would approach this as a breadth-first search algorithm for the `A` in a binary search tree of all possibilities where the node contain the value from either adding or subtracting the parent value).  It's a 2^m search space where `m` is the minimal number of moves.  You might be able to use dynamic programming to make this run in linear time.